# org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlertReceived: internal_error(80) for SOAP Web Service calls

Tags: security, java-7, bouncycastle, tls1.2, jboss5.x

**Error**: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message

**Issue details**: We are running our application with Jboss AS 5.1 and OpenJDK 7 (version 1.7.0_261), servers are Red Hat Linux CentOS 5.

We have a legacy application that makes several web service calls to NetSuite, after the recent NetSuite update of obsoleting the old cipher suites all our calls started failing. TLSv1.2 protocol is enabled (with -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 in run.conf), since it is Java 7 we added bouncy castle security jars to increase the supported cipher suites (as recommended in this comment by Igor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154932/2308058), with this, we were able to get the REST Web Service calls working but we are getting the error - org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlertReceived: internal_error(80) for SOAP WS calls.

Other things we tried but nothing seem to bring us luck yet:

1. Explicitly adding cipher suites that are supported by NetSuite in run.conf with -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2. Adding TLS protocol with tls.client.protocol in run.conf  - -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
3. Added self-signed cert to keystore
4. Added NetSuite's cert to Java cacerts

SOAP calls are working fine with Java 8 but moving this legacy application to Java 8 and Wild Fly is a very heavy lift so we are looking for alternative options.

*Any suggestions on getting this resolved would be very helpful, please! TIA!*

Answer (score 0):

TlsFatalAlertReceived means a fatal alert was received from the peer (i.e. NetSuite failed). internal_error would usually mean that something went wrong in the implementation itself, rather than any configuration match like cipher suites, however I don't know how careful NetSuite is about its choice of alerts. In any case, apart from guessing what the issue is, the real next step is to look at the NetSuite server logs to find what's failing.